# Swift Alamofire Image download and assign to ImageView in collectionView

Tags: swift

i am downloading Images by using alamofire from the api return, api returns hold the image urls and i download the image data from these urls in for loop using alamofire, but because of the async method the images in array are not ordered sequentially. Also even if I assign the images to the collectionview by using the reloadData() in main thread, i can't see the images after the view has initialized, but when i scroll the collectionView images are shown. I store the images in an Array.

```
func fetchData(){
    AF.request("https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=ab904f882bf94fa9960857911498aa78", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseJSON { AFdata in
                

                    do{
                        let game = try
                            JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: AFdata.data!)
                    
                        self.games = game
                        
                        if let gameResults = self.games?.results{
                            
                            for gameItem in gameResults{
                                AF.request(gameItem.backgroundImage!, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseData
                                    { AFdata in
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                             self.gameImages.append(UIImage(data: AFdata.data!)!)
                                        }
                                       
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.gamesCollectionView.reloadData()
                        }
                    
                    }catch let jsonErr{
                        print(jsonErr)
                    }
            }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GameCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! GameCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    cell.gameNameLabel.text = games?.results?[indexPath.item].name
    
    if(gameImages.count != games?.results?.count){
        cell.imageView.image = nil
    }else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = gameImages[indexPath.item]
    }
    
    return cell

}
```

}

Comment: You want to download all images before showing the collectionView? What about using `Alamofire+Image` which will let you have a method on `UIImageView` to set the image with a `URL`: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage Else SDWebImage, KingFisher will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

Here is demo

```
func fetchData(){
    AF.request("https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=ab904f882bf94fa9960857911498aa78", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseJSON { AFdata in
        
        
        do{
            let game = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: AFdata.data!)
            
            self.games = game
            
            if let gameResults = self.games?.results{
                let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() //<--- Here
                
                for gameItem in gameResults{
                    AF.request(gameItem.backgroundImage!, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseData
                    {
                        dispatchGroup.leave() //<--- Here
                        AFdata in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.gameImages.append(UIImage(data: AFdata.data!)!)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.gamesCollectionView.reloadData() //<--- Here
            }
            
            
        }catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call reload collectionView function inside of the AF.request complition block right before the game images appending. Because it needs time for fetch data but you are reloading collectionview before it fetch your images.

```
func fetchData(){
AF.request("https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=ab904f882bf94fa9960857911498aa78", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseJSON { AFdata in
            

                do{
                    let game = try
                        JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: AFdata.data!)
                
                    self.games = game
                    
                    if let gameResults = self.games?.results{
                        
                        for gameItem in gameResults{
                            AF.request(gameItem.backgroundImage!, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseData
                                { AFdata in
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                         self.gameImages.append(UIImage(data: AFdata.data!)!)
                        self.gamesCollectionView.reloadData()

                                    }
                                   
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                
                }catch let jsonErr{
                    print(jsonErr)
                }
        }
```

}

Comment: It works, but the order of the images are not sequantial as it is in the json, do u know any clue about it?

Comment: Because the response time of images is different then each other. You can use recursive function for solving that. Before you fetch the first image you don't fetch the other ones but this cause lots of performance issue. So I suggest that use KingFisher library for fetching images inside of the cell. This is the proper way to set image to imageview from remote server. @AtakanK

Comment: Also if it is solve your problem can you mark the answer correct? @AtakanK

Comment: The answer is correct but, I cant vote because i dont have enough reputation.